# Установка pickle

Tags: pip

В консоле windows ввожу команду `pip install cpickle`

```
Collecting cpickle
  Downloading cpickle-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                    
      File "c:\users\kaz19\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open                           
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\kaz19\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nnts2rx3\\cpickle\\setup.py'
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказывается в python 3.5 он уже установлен и называется просто pickle